# Determining the stationary points of the function $f(x,y) = 2x^2 + 2xy - y^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was studying for a quiz when a wild question appears. It goes like this:

> How can I determine the stationary points of the function $f(x,y) = 2x^2 + 2xy - y^3$?

**My Work**

Stationary points are points where the slope of the function becomes zero. With that in mind, I got to differentiate the above function and 
set its derivative to zero to get its stationary point.

Now implicitly differentiating the above equation:

$$z = 2x^2 + 2xy - y^3$$
$$dz = 4x + 2d(xy) - d(y^3)$$
$$dz = 4x + 2(xy' + y') - 3y^2y'$$
$$dz = 4x + 2xy' + 2y' - 3y^2 y'$$
$$dz = 4x + y'(2x + 2 - 3y^2)$$

Finally.....

$$ y' = \frac{dz - 4x}{2x + 2 - 3y^2} $$

With the form I got above, I see two derivatives, the $dz$ and $y'$. Setting the $dz$ and $y'$ to zero, I will get 
$x = 0$. Something's wrong.

How can I properly get the stationary points of the function $f(x,y) = 2x^2 + 2xy - y^3$?

Comment: It's a quiz for what course exactly? If it's a precalculus quiz (seeing that you tagged this question as `algebra-precalculus`), then I can't imaging how a question like this would end up on a quiz there. If it's a quiz on multivariate calculus, then I can't imagine you haven't been introduced at least to partial derivatives, and probably gradient too.

Comment: @zipirovich I was just actually answering questions found on the question bank....which would probably comes out on licensure board exams....

Answer (score 1):

The stationary points of a real valued function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  are those points $x_0$ where the derivative in every direction equals zero, or equivalently, the gradient is zero.

So, you have the gradient of $f$ is

$$\nabla f = (4x+y)\mathbf{i} + (2x-3y^2)\mathbf{j} = \mathbf{0}.$$

Comment: You mentioned of gradient, so the given equation must have been situated in a $3-D$ space. I thought I just been dealing in Cartesian coordinates, so I thought it's straightforward......

Comment: This is the first time I encountered that, so......maybe......show me how to get the stationary points of the above equation......and tell me what are the topics in mathematics that deals with those questions.......I was just actually answering questions found on the question bank.....